# Does HttpResponseStream buffers the data that it streams?

Tags: c#, http, httplistener

I'm serving HTTP requests with [HttpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx)

I use the synchronous HttpResponseStream.Write method to send data to the client.

Does `HttpResponseStream` buffer the data that it streams? I don't want it to. I just want send the data to the client immediately. If it does, how can I turn it off?